# why callback function inside a for loop is called just when the loop is done? Nodejs

Tags: node.js, for-loop, mongoose, callback

I have a for loop which basically readding some CSV parameters and returns data for each parameter (with HTTPS GET method). at the end of the loop a mongoose.save() callback function should save the data for each parameter in DB. the problem is that the LAST save(). function is calling only at the end of the loop - so if my CSV has 3 parameters inside  - the loop is running 3 times while skipping the save() function and only calling it at the end.

```
function loopCsv() {

for (var i = 0; i < product.csvData.length; i++) {

product.csvCogs = product.csvData[i][0];
const csvQuery = product.csvData[i][1]; 
const csvApiKey = process.env.API_KEY; 
product.csvUrl = "https://api.keepa.com/product?key=" + csvApiKey + "&domain=1&asin=" + csvQuery;


keepAliveAgent = new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true });
options = {
 method: "GET",
 headers: {
 "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
 "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
  "Connection": "Keep-Alive"
 }}
 options.agent = keepAliveAgent;

 https.get(product.csvUrl, options, function (response) {
 response = decompressResponse(response);

 var newData = '';

 response.on("data", function (chunk) {
   newData += chunk;
  //console.log(newData);
   });
   
 response.on("end", function () {
 asinData = JSON.parse(newData);
 setDataResponse(asinData); 

 pullAllData();
  
 createNewAsin();

 product.newAsin.save(function (err) {
 if (!err) {
   console.log('success');
 } else {
   console.log(err);
 }
 });
```

});
});

};

}

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a much more optimized way by calling `insertMany` rather than saving the value on each iteration, thus reducing DB calls.

Just push the data that you need to store into an array, and after the loop call `Model.insertMany(input_array)`

Comment: Thanks, Jithin I def try this. but I need that data will be saved in DB anyway.

Comment: I didn't the other use case, but if you are stubborn on saving it on each iteration, do the save function but put it on a `promise.all`